# Avoiding latency distortion at high denoise levels with DWT

Tags: discrete-signals, wavelet, denoising, dwt, discrete-wavelet-transform

I am denoising biological signals using the DWT, and for UI reasons would prefer the smoother waveform afforded by denoise level 5.  However, higher denoise levels seem to distort the latency of salient features (peaks). I've played around with different parametrizations (which converge to a function call of MATLAB's `wdencmp`):

- threshold methods (rigrsure, heursure)
- soft vs hard thresholds
- different mother wavelets

So far I've settled with threshold method: 'rigrsure', soft threshold, sym8 wavelet. I've also been playing around with padding/extending the signal on the front end of the signal, which sometimes [over] corrects the distortion.  That said, I don't have a great intuition for why padding length affects signal morphology the way it does (RMSE between the raw and denoised oscillates as padding length increases).

In the continued presence of latency distortion, I was wondering what other parametrizations, and pre processing steps I could explore to approach latency feature conservation in my signal.  I understand of course this is domain specific - but any pointers to techniques would be appreciated.

[image]

[Raw vs denoised signals - peak latencies are offset, especially trough #2 Red and blue are denoised.]